# Horizontal progress bar is not increasing to show progress in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar

I have a set of methods and each method takes time to do its task.

For instance,

After Method `setRules()` is executed,

- *The progress level should increase to `30`.*

After Method `getLogs()` is executed,

- *The progress level should increase to `60`.*

After Method `getChartView()` is executed,

- *The progress level should increase to `100`.*

***But the `ProgressBar` increases till `30` and not goes beyond that although my all the methods are executing.***

**Code -**

```
public class DialogPopup extends DialogFragment 
{

    private static int myProgress=0;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus=0;
    private Handler myHandler=new Handler();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,container, false);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        beginYourTask();

        return view;
    }

    public void beginYourTask()
    {
        myProgress=0;
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.myProgress);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /*Do some work in background thread*/ 
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {

          @Override
          public void run() 
          {             
            progressStatus=setRules();  
            myHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            });

            progressStatus=getLogs();   
            myHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            });

            progressStatus=getChartView();  
            myHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            }); 

            /*Hides the Progress bar*/
            myHandler.post(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progressStatus=0; 
                    myProgress=0;
                }
            });

        }

        private int setRules()
        {
            //Code here takes time

            //set progress to 30
            return 30;
        }

        private int getLogs()
        {
            //Code here takes time

            //set progress to 60    

            return 60;
        }

        private int getChartView()
        {
            //Code here takes time

            //set progress to 100
            return 100; 
        }
    }).start();
 }
```

**NOTE:**

I took the help to create such Progress Bar from the tutorial -[android-progress-bar-horizontal](http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-progress-bar-horizontal/).

Comment: you are assigning two different progress bars to progressBar variable. why?

Comment: and why do you want to use invalidate()? what's that?

Comment: do you insist on using dialog fragment, i will just be able to post one progressDialog that simulate your task if you want ?

Comment: @mmlooloo - I found that `progressDialog` isn't working correctly with dialog fragment. So I am forced to use `ProgressBar`. Are you saying that you can use `progressDialog` with dialog fragment that simulate my task ? The normal way of using `progressDialog` is well known but not how to use it with dialog fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask for this kind of thing:

```
public void beginYourTask()
{
    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>(){

   @Override
   public Void doInBackground(Void...params){
       publishProgress(setRules());
       publishProgress(getLogs());
       publishProgress(getChartView());
       return null;
   } 

     @Override
     public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

   }.execute();
}
```

That's the idea, there may be typos.

The tutorial from your link hasn't been updated for a while and normally you don't want to use a `Thread` in this situation because `AsyncTask` is designed to save you from all the thread problems you would encounter while using `Thread`

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) on this and you'll know when to use a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Where to use `invalidate()` ? I am using `setProgress` inside `run()` method so can I use `invalidate()` inside `run()` ? I tried your code but now progress bar is not increasing at all.

Comment: You probably want to use AsyncTask for this, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Compile time error - `doInBackground()` requires return type. How to set the return type for each of the 3 methods in `doInBackground()` to show progress ? The `doInBackground()` will give the final return type of 100 which is useless to show the increased progress.

Comment: OK, your methods have to do something that takes time otherwise all 3 steps will complete and showing 100% in the progress bar

Comment: Now I am getting Null Pointer Exception at `onProgressUpdate()` at line `progressBar.setProgress(progress[0])`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59271/discussion-between-tom91136-and-ved-prakash).

Comment: My methods are not empty. There is huge code in all these methods and they are taking time. However, I am getting null pointer exception when return type of `doInBackground()` is set to null.

Comment: the return type of `doInBackground()` have no use in your case, we are not using the result. the return value of `doInBackground()` gets passed to `onPostExecute()`, which ignores the `result`